# Swift @escaping params optional

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (SwiperElement, SwiperItemResource, Dragging) -> Content
```

I am self-learning swift. Please help.

1. what can I call the name of the above code style? Callback, function,..?
2. I want to set optional for some cases, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's kind of callback, called `closure`, more information here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html
2. If you want to set optional just adding suffix like `SwiperElement?`

Answer (score 0):

**@ViewBuilder** is a custom parameter attribute that constructs views from **closures**.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder

**Use buildif** for optional content when using view builder
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildif(_:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (SwiperElement, SwiperItemResource, Dragging) -> Content
```

Is not a valid syntax: you need to either specify a `var`, in which case you don't need to say `@escaping`:

```
@ViewBuilder var content: (SwiperElement, SwiperItemResource, Dragging) -> Content
```

or define a `func`, where you can say the closure is `@escaping`:

```
@ViewBuilder func myFunc(content: @escaping (SwiperElement, SwiperItemResource, Dragging) -> Content) -> some View { ... }
```

In first case you declare a variable, which stores a type called [Closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html). This type has 3 inputs `SwiperElement, SwiperItemResource, Dragging`, and 1 output of type `Content`.

In second case you define a function, which will get a closure as its argument. Keywords `@escaping` means that the closure will outlive the function itself (i.e. when function returns, it's possible that closure is still running).

Regarding optionals, depends what you mean. If you want to set some parameters as optional, you just add `?` to them:

```
var x(SwiperElement?, SwiperItemResource?, Dragging?) -> Content?
```

but if you are talking about optional UI elements, then you may need to get familiar with SwiftUI `@State`, e.g. as explained [here](https://medium.com/macoclock/conditional-views-in-swiftui-dc09c808bc30)